# Windows 7 System Crash

Tags: windows-7, crash, maintenance, administration

I am using a Laptop running Windows 7. For past few days, the system crashes for no apparent reason( as much as I know) .

Either the system crashes or become unresponsive which requires a hard reboot.

I am pretty sure, there are number of reasons that a system could crash, Is there any way that I could check the reasons either through analyzing log files or dump which it creates while crashing.

Here is the system configuration for geeks.

System : Asus,
Operating System : Windows 7 Professional (64-bit)

Processor : Intel core i5 CPU M430, 2.27GHz
RAM : 4GB

External Connectivity : 22inch LCD monitor

Comment: We need event logs or minidumps to even begin to diagnose what is happening.  What have you done differently in the past few days?  New Updates?  New Hardware?  More information would be very helpful

Comment: I did install few softwares in the last few days. And I am not expert in the Crash dump analysis. Also, I donot know whether it is from the new software for sure.  Is there anyway that I could check for myself what could be the issue ? BTW, no hardware or system updates.

Comment: Start by undoing anything you did.  If you installed an instant msging program, and now its crashing, all signs point to that program right?  So start there, take it back to where you were a couple days ago (before the crashing) and let us know.

Comment: @Francisswest, Thanks I will try undoing and uninstalling all the softwares that I installed in last 2 weeks(I suppose). My fear is if it does not fix the problem. By analyzing the crash dump, can we definitively tell, the crash happens for this exact reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running a virus scan? Crashes could be caused by a number of things, but I find that a virus scan is a good place to start: http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/

Comment: I will try running a system scan. BTW, I have Security essentials installed. , I hope it helps.